# Problem about running php test case using Selenium RC

Tags: php, selenium-rc

I use Mozilla Firefox 4. I can run a php test case with selenium RC, but when I run the test case I found the following error for every test case from command line.
....

> failed to start new browser session: java.lang.RuntimeException
>   :firefox 3 could not be found in the path. please add the directory
>   containing " firefox.exe" to your path environment variable or
>   explicitly specify a path to Firefox 3 like this
>
> *firefox3c:\blash\firefox.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we write

```
$this->setBrowser("*firefox /usr/bin/firefox"); // For Linux its the Path of Firefox File.
```

but in Windows

```
$this->setBrowser("*firefox")     // It takes Default Path C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox
```

If you are trying to run on another specific browser according to versions then you have to specify the path of file where your firfox.exe is stored.

Thanks.